# Does application preferences remain after Android system upgrade?

Tags: android, system, upgrade, android-preferences

I want to store preferences which are Android version dependent (eg. User Agent string obtained from `WebView`).

When user is upgrading system (say from 1.6 to 2.1), does those preferences last?

I want to retrieve User Agent from `WebView` once, then store it in `SharedPreferences`. When system is upgraded I want to update this value.

Comment: Are you talking about SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes - my shared preferences created internally in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course they'll stay.
Each app has it's own storage for preferences and they can be cleared when app is removed or in "Manage applications" by pressing "Clear Data" button for selected app.

Comment: Well, same thing when you update your desktop OS. New version of system files, libs, executables, etc. are written over old OS.
Why this should remove your SharedPrefs? Some API deprecation\removal is possible, but not data destruction :)